# The reverse implication in the stability theory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Let us consider the system of differential equation $\dot x=Ax+h(t),$ where A is a constant matrix of dimension $n\geq2$ and $h$ is continuous on $[0,\infty).$ All eigenvalues of $A$ have a negative real part. It is known, that $h(t)\to 0$ for $t\to\infty$ implies that all solutions $x(t)$ of $\dot x=Ax+h(t)$ converge to $0$ for $t\to\infty.$ 
Is the converse implication true too? (All solutions $x(t)\to 0$ implies $h(t)\to 0$).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

More precisely, the equivalence holds if for some vector norm $\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert,$
\begin{equation}
\sup\limits_{0\leq u\leq1}\left\Vert\int\limits_{t}^{t+u}h(s)ds\right\Vert\to 0 
\end{equation}
as $t\to\infty.$

For the details and (long) proof see Theorem B in:

*Strauss, A.; Yorke, J. A.*, [**Perturbing uniform asymptotically stable nonlinear systems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-0396(69)90004-7), J. Differ. Equations 6, 452-483 (1969). [ZBL0182.12103](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0182.12103).

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider $h$ which is $0$ everywhere except near $n^2$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ where it has bumps of height $1$ and width $1/n$:
$$
h(t) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb N} 1_{[n^2-1/n,n^2+1/n]}(t).
$$
Consider now for instance $x'(t)=-x(t)+h(t)$.
All trajectories become eventually positive. Then it's clear that the effect of $h$ perturbs $x$ by at most $2/n$ when $t$ passes the time $n$:
$$
x(n+1/n)-x(n-1/n) \leq \int_{n^2-1/n}^{n^2+1/n} h(t)\,dt=2/n.
$$
From this you should be able to conclude that $x$ goes to $0$ nonetheless, because in the interval $[n^2,(n+1)^2]$ of length $\sim n$ it has plenty of time to become exponentially close to $0$.